# how to put just a couple label to a swarm plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I've written the following code and it gave a plot with 8 labels and I just need 2 of them which are specified for a certain color.

```
plt.figure(dpi=100)
sns.swarmplot(x="model", y="f_train", data=df, palette=["b"], label="train f-score")
sns.swarmplot(x="model", y="f_test", data=df, palette=["r"], label="test f-score")
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(rotation=-45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And its clear that I need one train f-score and one test f-score for my labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your data frame is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"model":np.repeat(["A","B","C"],4),
                  "f_train":np.random.uniform(0,1,12),
                  "f_test":np.random.uniform(0,1,12)})
```

You can melt it and use the column names as "hue=" :

```
sns.swarmplot(data=df.melt(id_vars="model"),x="model",y="value",hue="variable")
```

[image]

Comment: I'd updated my data frame and then it worked with this code. Thanks alot.